# no transform from xxx to xxx after installing conda

Tags: roslaunch, urdf, python3

the previous package I created can be used smoothly.However,after installing conda and pytorch,the robot description cannot be put on screen correctly.The early verison of robot description in rviz shows the failure of continuous link transform.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe after you've installed conda, ROS may not be pointing to the default python path (usually on /usr/bin/python3).

You can check the python version which is being called:

```
which python3
```

If this points to the Conda environment rather than the system Python, it might cause a problem. You might need to adjust the PATH or PYTHONPATH to prioritize the system Python when working with ROS 2.

As a temporal solution try to deactivate conda

```
conda deactivate

source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
```

As Pytorch, and AI tools usually generate conflicts and require different dependencies (diff Python versions), etc, this can lead to issues as you're experiencing (I also had a lot). That is why I recommend creating different virtual environments for each application you have on your system and installing the dependencies in each one, isolating each one of them.

Comment: thank you for your response!I add the command 'conda deactivate' in .bash and succeed.Now I need to close and open conda manually.

Comment: Great! I do the same for my conda applications!